# Incorrectly Configured lookup_field error in ```HyperlinkedModelSerializer```

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Myself **Dhinesh**. But  I'm a beginner at `Django Rest Framework`. Here, I'm trying to change the lookup_field from `pk` to a custom field (`IP_Address`). But I'm getting this error again and again. Help to resolve this issue.

Getting `` ImproperlyConfigured at /api/nodes/192.168.1.200/ Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "nodemaster-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field. ``

**Models.py**

```
class NodeMaster(models.Model):
    Device_Manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices = MANUFACTURER)
    Device_Type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices = DEVICE_TYPE)
    Physical_Location = models.CharField(max_length= 50, null= True)
    IP_Address =  models.CharField(max_length=50,unique = True )
    Community_String = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.IP_Address
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class NodeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = NodeMaster
        fields = '__all__'
        lookup_field = "IP_Address"
```

**views.py**

```
class NodeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = NodeSerializer
    queryset = NodeMaster.objects.all()
    lookup_field = "IP_Address"
```

**urls.py**

```
node_list = NodeViewSet.as_view({
    'get':'list',
    'post' : 'create'
})

node_detail = NodeViewSet.as_view({
    'get':'retrieve',
    'put' : 'update',
    'patch' : 'partial_update',
    'delete' : 'destroy'
})

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns([
    path('', node_list, name = 'nodemaster-list'),
    path('<str:IP_Address>/', node_detail, name='nodemaster-detail')
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently according to DjangoRestframework documentation in https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.1-announcement/#deprecations
lookup_field was removed but they suggest using extra_kwargs for that. Otherwise just removing lookup_field removed the error for my code.